# Passport.js authentication in ExpressJS not returning res.user in React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, passport.js

I've followed a guide on Medium on the implementation of Passport js with a MERN stack and whilst I got authentication to work, I'm struggling to persist users between routes. Below are snippets of my code:

## Backend

Server.js setup (part of it):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')
const passport = require('./passport/setup')

const MONGO_URI = 'db'

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(console.log(`MongoDB connected ${MONGO_URI}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))

app.set("")

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (PORT !== 5000) {
  app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
}

app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
}))
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MONGO_URI })
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Passport.js Local Strategy setup:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/User')

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, (email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No User Found' })
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    if (isMatch) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, { message: "Wrong Password" });
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return done(null, false, { message: err });
        });
})
);

module.exports = passport;
```

Login route:

```
router.post("/new-login", async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: err });
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: "No user found" });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ errors: err });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({ success: `logged in ${user.id}` });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
})
```

## Frontend React:

Posting Login Data:

```
export const postData = async (url, data) => {
    try {
        console.log('posting this ', data)
        const config = {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'backend',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
            }
        }
        const response = await axios.post(url, data, config);
        console.log('getting this', response)
        return {
            data: response.data,
            error: "",
            success: true,
        };
    } catch (exp) {
        console.log('Error', exp)
        return {
            success: false,
            error: exp.response.data,
        };
    }
};
```

Axios call:

```
let response = await postData('/login/new-login', { email, password })
```

When trying to login all of this works and returns the login success message with user.id from the login route, but when I look at the Axios response there's no reference to any user or session as shown below:

[image: Response from Axios request]

I'm probably not understanding how users are passed to React from the backend but shouldn't res.user exist here following req.LogIn in Passport? Or should I take the user.id and save it in a global React state and attach it every time I do a request to a protected route? Right now if I do a GET request to a protected route I get a req.user undefined message.

Frontend Axios call:

```
export const getData = async (url) => {
    console.log('not called?')
    try {
        const config = {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'backend',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
            }
        }
        const response = await axios.get(url, config);
        console.log('response? ', response)
        return {
            data: response.data,
            error: "",
            success: true,
        };
    } catch (exp) {
        return {
            success: false,
            error: exp.response.data,
        }
    }
}
```

Backend Protected Route:

```
router.get("/new-protected", passport.authorize('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), (req, res) => {
    console.log('whats request?', req.user)
    res.send(`Hello, logged in`);
})
```

When trying this I remove the middleware to see what req looks like, but I always get undefined req.user, so I'm guessing either I'm supposed to be passing req.user somehow in my axios call or I'm not retrieving a user when logging in initially, any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: your frontend and backend are separated with different URL ?

Comment: @ShueiYang that's right, my frontend is hosted on Vercel and backend on Railway

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything about the user's data once you log in with authorization, the passport middleware is here for the job, however we should at least set up the right condition for them to exchange the credential, try to change the setting a bit to see how it go :

this part :

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: //put the EXACT URL you host from Vercel 
  method: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
  credentials: true,
}))
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(
   session({
     secret: "secret",
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: MONGO_URI })
  })
);
app.use(express.json()); // optional: you can uninstall bodyParser since express have now his own module so you can just replace with this line. 

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

and update a bit this part at the frontend Axios call :

```
const config = {
    withCredentials: true,
};
```

I don't know if you have already the issue in localhost or after deployment, if it sill not working than we may have to fix on the cookie session.